# Am I using renamed types correctly in Golang?

Tags: go

I have to deal with huge integers in Golang that come in from a Swagger-defined REST API. Since Swagger needs a `Validate(strfmt.Registry)`, I define my custom type like this:

```
// BigInt is a big.Int, but includes a Validate() method for swagger
// Once created, it can be used just like a big.Int.
type BigInt struct {
    *big.Int
}
```

Since it needs to be transformed to and from JSON, I define some JSON Marshaling interface:

```
// UnmarshalJSON implements encoding/json/RawMessage.UnmarshalJSON
func (b *BigInt) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &b.Int)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

// MarshalJSON calls json.Marshal() on the BigInt.Int field.
func (b *BigInt) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if b == nil {
        return []byte("null"), nil
    }
    return json.Marshal(b.Int)
}
```

Now I realized that my custom type doesn't actually behave exactly like `big.Int`. In order to compare two BigInts:

```
example := BigInt{Int: &big.Int{}}
other := BigInt{Int: &big.Int{}}
example.Cmp(other.Int)
```

I cannot do

```
example.Cmp(other)
```

which is much cleaner. And creating the BigInt is also a terrible experience, which I have to wrap in a function like this:

```
// NewBigInt creates a BigInt with its Int struct field 
func NewBigInt() (i *BigInt) {
    return &BigInt{Int: &big.Int{}}
}
```

1. Is this really how I'm supposed to do things?
2. Why can't golang treat big.Int just like its other built in types like `int64/uint64/float64`?

Comment: Does it need to be a pointer? If you embed big.Int as is, then you can use `&BigInt{}` instead of `&BigInt{Int: &big.Int{}}`.

Comment: And `big.Int` already implements json's Marshaler and Unmarshaler interfaces, so you don't need to do that. There's not much you can do about `example.Cmp(other.Int)` other than declaring delegate methods for every single of the `big.Int`'s methods, or at least the ones that your app is using.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this really how I'm supposed to do things?

It's *a* way to do it, but it's not what I'd call a "renamed" type; it's a struct containing a single field. You could also do (like, for example, [`time.Duration`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration)):

```
type BigInt *big.Int
```

And apply methods to it. This would allow you to seamlessly convert between `*big.Int` and your type.

> Why can't golang treat big.Int just like its other built in types like int64/uint64/float64?

Because unlike those types, `big.Int` isn't a built-in type; you can tell because it's `big.Int`, i.e., it's defined in a package, not in the language.

Comment: I just tried this and there's a huge problem - `BigInt` can't use any of `big.Int`'s methods! Which is apparently why I went to the anonymous struct way of doing this. Perhaps renaming a type simply isn't what one should do here at all?

Comment: Yes, you'd have to convert back to `big.Int` to use its methods. You may need to reconsider your design starting from your original goal/requirement.

Comment: This is a wrong answer: in fact that is not a struct containing a single field: that's a struct that _embed_ *big.Int: see https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding

Comment: @Cirelli94 that's not accurate. Embedded fields are still fields. The struct has one field, and it is an embedded field.

Comment: [From the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types): "A struct is a sequence of named elements, called fields, each of which has a name and a type. Field names may be specified explicitly (IdentifierList) or implicitly (EmbeddedField)."

Comment: @Cirelli94 even if it did work like you thought it did, that still wouldn't even make the answer wrong, since the solution is *not to use a struct at all*.

Comment: Yes, I agree, your solution is not wrong! Struct is not to use at all, embedding does not solve problems here.
Thanks for your time!!!